# cv2.putText not showing Armenian letters on screen in python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am coming to a problem that I am trying to output Armenian letter when I am using my hand which is a sign language application. So, then I am getting "???" why signing a letter. I believe the putText() of opencv is not either deprecated or having issues or maybe not implementing the proper way. Please help. thanks!

Here is my code:

```
 dict_letter = {0: 'Ա', 1: 'Բ', 2: 'Գ', 3: 'Դ', 4: 'Ե', 5: 'Զ', 6: 'Է', 7: 'Ը', 8: 'Թ', 9: 'Ժ', 10: 'Ի', 11: 'Լ', 12: 'Խ', 13: 'Ծ', 14: 'Կ', 15: 'Հ',
                16: 'Ձ', 17: 'Ղ', 18: 'Ճ', 19: 'Մ', 20: 'Յ', 21: 'Ն', 22: 'Շ', 23: 'Ո', 24: 'Չ', 25: 'Պ', 26: 'Ջ', 27: 'Ռ', 28: 'Ս', 29: 'Վ', 30: 'Տ', 31: 'Ր',
                 32: 'Ց', 33: 'Փ', 34: 'Ք', 35: 'Ֆ'}

img = cv2.putText(image_hand,
                                   f"{dict_letter[pred]} - {str(probabs)}",
                                  (x_square, y_square - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                                   0.6, (0,0,0), 2)
```

Using Pillow:

```
            cv2_im_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    pil_im = Image.fromarray(cv2_im_rgb)

                    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_im)

# Choose a font
                    font = ImageFont.truetype("/arnamu.ttf", 50)

# Draw the text
                    draw.text((0, 0), dict_letter[pred], font=font)
```

Comment: since you're new, may I suggest you take the [tour]?

Answer (score 1):

The builtin vector fonts don't come with those glyphs. Or at least you can't rely on that. There are extensions of the Hershey vector fonts for some unicode. I don't know if OpenCV ships with those.

You can try the `freetype` module from the `contrib` repository. It has bugs too. Right-to-left script is/was broken. Random usage example: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14579 (`createFreeType2`, `loadFontData` on the instance, then use `.putText`)

In OpenCV v5 (no release date yet) there will be proper font support.

Comment: I checked the `freetype` but I need some help on the implementation of that  module and cant find any implementation starters

Comment: `pip install opencv-contrib-python` and make sure you do **not** have other opencv-python packages installed. they're mutually exclusive. documentation for the freetype-support module is here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/dfa/classcv_1_1freetype_1_1FreeType2.html I'm sure you can translate to Python. there's plenty of python code for it on the internet too.

Comment: example code I wrote a while ago: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14579

Answer (score 1):

The function putText() in OpenCV uses [Hershey fonts](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga0f9314ea6e35f99bb23f29567fc16e11). This is the [full set](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/hershey/hershey1.gif) of available characters in Hershey. If your special language characters are not available in the set, it means this is the reason why it doesn't work.

Here's how you can use Pillow to add text instead of OpenCV.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
 
# Open an Image
img = Image.open('my_img.png')
 
I1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
 
# Add Text to image
I1.text((28, 36), "nice image", fill=(255, 0, 0))
 
# Display edited image
img.show()
 
# Save the edited image
img.save("my_img2.png")
```

Comment: ya... is not in there... is there any alternative to fix it ?

Comment: You may use Pillow to add the text. It supports other fonts and it's easy to use too. :)

Comment: since this answer closely resembles my own given earlier, I'd like to ask: do *you* know what character set of Hershey is shipped with OpenCV? there are extensions to many planes of unicode. the picture you linked to seems to be the set from 1976 but I see no claims on that site on whether that is what OpenCV comes with.

Comment: You may download the set and check it on your own if you wish to see what characters are available for Hershey in general. :)

Comment: @EsraaAbdelmaksoud can you show me you way of the implementation of Pillow by adding the text?

Comment: @user18573205 Sure! I'll just edit my answer to add it.

Comment: Alright. Will try it soon and let you know :) thanks

Comment: You're always welcome! :)

Comment: I tried your example but for some reason is not working I am getting an error:`ttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'load'` is the my update code pillow okay ?

Comment: What line of the pillow code caused it?

Comment: Well the open an image and add text to the image... Remember in my code `image_hand` is using the live camera and `dict_letter[pred]` is the letters that I am trying to print

Comment: i updated my code - under pillow label .. please see.. right now I dont get any foreign language letter showing

Comment: Why are you using OpenCV putText again after using Pillow?

Comment: please show me full implementation replicating my code above without using opencv

Comment: remember i dont have real image.. im using my live camera feed

Comment: I updated my code again.. now it does not even show the ?? just a blank text

Comment: I can't see "fill" in your code. It means you're choosing nothing for the color. Please refer to the documentation for required arguments. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html