# Displaying Marathi(Non English Characters) using PIL library onto the OpenCV Interface not working as needed

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, translation, google-translation-api

I am working on a project where I am using OpenCV and Python to recognize English gestures from webcam feed and translate them into Marathi language. However, I am facing an issue with the translation process. Currently, my code translates English gestures into Marathi pronunciation, but I want to achieve true Marathi translations. For example, when the gesture for "Hello" is recognized, I get the the Marathi translation as 'हॅलो', I want the translation to be "नमस्कार" (which means "Namaskar" in Marathi).
I am using the python PIL library as shown in this article :[Python OpenCV putText() show (non-ascii, unicode, utf) character symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71962098/python-opencv-puttext-show-non-ascii-unicode-utf-character-symbols)

Additionally, I also want to ensure that numbers are displayed the same instead of random Marathi alphabet letters. For example, for "1" it displays random alphabet 'ख'.

```py
pil_image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_image)
english_text = ' '.join(sentence)
translated_text = ' '.join(translated)
draw.text((3, 30), english_text, fill=(255, 255, 255), font=font)
draw.text((3, image.shape[0] - 40), translated_text, fill=(255, 255, 255), font=font)
```

This the code that I'm using to display the Image on Opencv feed.
Is there a way to Fix my problem?

Comment: The problem is probably in your translation (however that is done, you didn't show us), not in OpenCV or any of the code you've provided in the question so far...

Comment: What MT engine are you using?

Comment: @DanMašek For translation I'm using googletrans library ``def translate_to_marathi(text):
    translator = Translator()
    translation = translator.translate(text, src='en', dest='mr')
    return translation.text``

Comment: @MrNobody your code returns `'नमस्कार'` rather than `'हॅलो'`, so googletrans appears to be doing what it should and what you require. What is the value of `text` that you are passing to the function when you get `'हॅलो'`? Could you adapt your code to print `text` value within function? Both as a string, and a sequence of bytes?